# Adaptive - Autoscaling Y Range when updating a bar plot in bokeh through select widget

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, bokeh

I am not sure if my question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738372/python-bokeh-range-does-not-change-upon-update) [or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467451/bokeh-server-update-axe-scale), but they are not reproducibile and confusing.

**It is possible in Bokeh, when I use the [select widget](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#select) and I update a plot, to update x-y ranges?**

This is particularly useful when dealing with data different in magnitude.

```
dictonary={'Station':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'],'Passengers':[20,30,40,20,10000,15000,20000,8000,16000],'Date':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dictonary)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

def modify_doc(doc):
    station_list=['a','b']
    station_selected='a'
    df_r=df.copy()
    x_name='Date'
    y_name='Passengers'
    xrange=[0,df_r.Date.iloc[-1]]
    yrange=[0,df_r[y_name].max()]
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=df_r)
    hover=HoverTool(tooltips=[('Passengers','@Passengers'),('Station','@Station'),('Date','@Date')])
    plot=figure(title='Passengers for station',tools=[hover,'pan','wheel_zoom'], plot_width=400, plot_height=400,x_range=(xrange), y_range=(yrange))
    plot.vbar(x="Date", top="Passengers",source=source, width=1.5)
    def update_plot(attr, old, new):
        activity =  select.value
        data = df_r[df_r['Station'] == activity]
        source.data = ColumnDataSource(data=data).data


    select = Select(title='Select Station', value=station_selected, options=station_list)
    select.on_change('value', update_plot)

    layout=column(select, plot)
    doc.add_root(layout)
show(modify_doc)
```

Here the screenshoots of the outputs:

[image: Station 'a' before zooming]

[image: Station 'a' after zooming]

[image: Station 'b' before zooming]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
yrange=[0, df_r[y_name].max()]
```

You are *turning off* automatic data-ranging and assuming all responsibility to update ranges yourself. If you want automatic data-ranging, don't set `y_range` in the call to `figure` at all. If you want one half of the range pinned (e.g. to zero), you can do this:

```
plot.y_range.start = 0
```